# .NET Environment.NewLine - how to setup programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, newline, environment

I would like to change the default Environment.NewLine character for my current environment.

I have one standalone application that is writing messages to a console. When the core framework works in the console environment the new line is \r\n. When I move the core framework into a Windows service the Environment.NewLine changes to "\n".

I would like to be able to change the Console to always use "\r\n" because when I redirect the output of the console to a file the output has no "windows new lines" when read from example Notepad.

I would like Console.WriteLine to use \r\n whenever I want.

**EDIT:**

I am redirecting Console.out:

```
        ConsoleOut = File.AppendText(fileName);
        ConsoleOut.AutoFlush = true;


        Console.SetOut(ConsoleOut);
        Console.SetError(ConsoleOut);
```

Every Console.WriteLine or Console.Write is sent to a file but as I said I am experiencing different behaviours in Windows Service and in standalone Windows environment.

Comment: These two statements are contradictory: "When the core framework works in the console environment the new line is \r\n", and "I would like Console.WriteLine to use \r\n whenever I want".

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` is a constant. http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline

Comment: Why then if I run the same library from windows service the Console.WriteLine outputs me \n instead of \r\n. I Redirected the Console.out to a file. The same code runs in two different environment.

Comment: I've just checked my logs from one of my services; it is definitely CRLF, i.e. bytes 13, 10. I think you need to a: double check your files, b: check you haven't changed them later (for example, during transfer over FTP), and c: provide an example that *actually shows* it generating either CR or LF but not CRLF

Comment: I will check them deeply. Thanks. You gave me a big help with you code samples but I still do not know where is the problem so I will wait to assign the answer until I find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not convinced by this:

> When I move the core framework into a Windows service the Environment.NewLine changes to "\n"

I've checked the IL for `get_NewLine()`, and it is hard-coded to:

```
ldstr "\r\n"
ret
```

So basically; the problem isn't what you think it is; changing `Environment.NewLine` isn't going to do anything (and: isn't possible).

So: how are you redirecting? I tend to just do something like:

```
if (!Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    var tw = new SlowWriter(Path.Combine(logPath,"{0}.log"));
    Console.SetError(tw);
    Console.SetOut(tw);
}
```

where `SlowWriter` is a custom type (subclasses `TextWriter`) that makes sure the file doesn't stay open; slower, but pretty robust:

```
class SlowWriter : TextWriter
{ // this opens and closs each time; slower, but doesn't lock the file
    private readonly string path;
    public SlowWriter(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }
    public override System.Text.Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
    private TextWriter Append()
    {
        var finalPath = string.Format(path, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        return File.AppendText(finalPath);
    }
    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            using (var file = Append())
            {
                file.Write(value);
            }
        }
    }
    public override void Write(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            using (var file = Append())
            {
                file.Write(buffer, index, count);
            }
        }
    }
    public override void Write(char[] buffer)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            using (var file = Append())
            {
                file.Write(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. I am redirecting the Console.out

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify System.Environment.NewLine

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

It's a readonly property

```
public static string NewLine { get; }
```

And [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/newline) you can read that NewLine return always "\r\n".

> Next we look into get_NewLine and it is implemented with this IL. You
>   can see it simply returns the "\r\n" string literal.

So I think you can use a Constant inside your application like

```
public const NEWLINE = "\r\n";
```

And simply use this instead of Environment.NewLine.

Console.WriteLine don't use internally Environment.NewLine instead it use a carriage return followed by a line feed. Reference [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdf6yhx5.aspx)

> The default line terminator is a string whose value is a carriage
>   return followed by a line feed ("\r\n" in C#, or vbCrLf in Visual
>   Basic). You can change the line terminator by setting the
>   TextWriter.NewLine property of the Out property to another string. The
>   example provides an illustration.

There is also an example on how to modify this property :

```
 // Redefine the newline characters to double space.
 Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: I agree that System.Environment.NewLine  cannot be modified. I supposed that Console.WriteLine is using System.Environment.NewLine

Comment: Edited the answer with new information about Console.Writeline

Comment: If this Console.Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";  works then this is the answer I a looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Then I don't think you should use `Environment.NewLine`. What you see is the exact reason why the have it in the first place. I think you are better off by defining an `appSettings` that you use and set it to different values for your console application and the windows service application.

*Update:* 
Also see Marc Gravell's answer. Even though if it is hard coded I wouldn't try to change it with the motivation as above.

Comment: I am not using it. I only supposed that Console.WriteLine is using it.